# Expo Push Notification does not receive notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I am trying to use Expo's Snack Tool to test the notification system.

I manage to get my token and send a scheduled notification, but can't figure out how to receive a notification from the test tool proposed by Expo. I have also use Insomnia for making my POST request and just return me a 200.

Here is the link to a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@biblizar/expo-push-notification) as well as the one of the [test tool](https://expo.dev/notifications)

Comment: Hello did you managed to solve this?

Comment: No, we had give up this feature since we can't solve it

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Expo tool but I would suggest you use Prateek Bhutani's
(postman plugin) I have tested my apps in past using postman.

link : https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3

Comment: I've try with Insomnia and got a status 200 with a ok message but my app doesn't receive the notification